# Get difference in days between two weekdays

Tags: c#, .net, date, calendar

This sounds very easy, but i don't get the point.

So what's the easiest way to get number of days between two `DayOfWeeks` when the first one is the starting point? If the next weekday is earlier, it should considered to be in the next week.

The [DayOfWeek-Enumeration](http://%20%20%5B1%5D%3a%20http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek.aspx) starts with `Sunday(0)` and ends with `Saturday(6)`.

```
 1. Monday    = 1
 2. Thursday  = 4

Result: 4 - 1 = 3

 1. Thursday  = 4
 2. Monday    = 1
// obviously a Math.Abs is helpful
Result: Math.Abs(1 - 4) = 3
```

But this result is wrong because there are 4 days between Thursday and Monday(next week).

Comment: What about the edge case when the two DayOfWeeks are the same? Is that zero or seven?

Comment: @Bob: Then the difference should be 0.

Comment: I believe you need 7-basis arithmetic (not 10-basis standard)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Add 7, then mod 7:

```
(7 + (1 - 4)) % 7
```

For example:

```
var weekDay1  = DayOfWeek.Thursday;
var weeekDay2 = DayOfWeek.Monday;
var daysDiff  = (7 + (weeekDay2 - weekDay1)) % 7;
```

Comment: +1 this is what I was thinking, too. I was hung up on the abs() of it all.

Comment: @mbeckish: added an example. Thanks for assistance :)