# ASP.NET/C#: Get nearest future date based from list of days

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, dayofweek

I would like to get the nearest based from a list of days:

**Scenario 1:**

```
Date: July 22, 2013 (Monday)
Possible days: "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Friday" (string values)
Answer: July 23, 2013 (Tuesday)
```

**Scenario 2:**

```
Date: July 23, 2013 (Tuesday)
Possible days: "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Saturday"
Answer: July 24, 2013 (Wednesday)
```

**Scenario 3:**

```
Date: July 24, 2013 (Wednesday)
Possible days: "Monday", "Tuesday"
Answer: July 29, 2013 (Monday)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: nearest upcoming day only or past as well?

Comment: @EhsanUllah Just the future dates. (updated the details)

Comment: Check first scenario please. 22 is Monday and 21 is Tuesday, how you got it?

Comment: Based on scenario 03, I believe that upcoming only

Comment: i can give you an idea. Get the source day and compare it with the possible days. The smaller the difference the nearest the day. You can add that to your source date then.

Comment: Noted, @Uriil. Got the wrong day.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12241077/given-a-list-of-dates-how-do-i-get-the-nearest-date-in-the-past-to-today-and-th

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse("July 22, 2013");
        DayOfWeek dateDay = date.DayOfWeek;
        DayOfWeek[] possibleDays = { DayOfWeek.Tuesday,DayOfWeek.Wednesday,DayOfWeek.Friday };
        int addToBestAnswer = 7;
        foreach (var checkDay in possibleDays)
        {
            if (checkDay-dateDay<addToBestAnswer)
            {
                addToBestAnswer = checkDay - dateDay;
            }
        }
        DateTime Answer = date.AddDays(addToBestAnswer);
```

Edit: for only string input:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse("July 22, 2013");
        string[] possibleDays={ "Tuesday","Wednesday","Friday" };

        List<int> pDays = new List<int>();
        foreach (var inputDay in possibleDays)
        {
            pDays.Add(int.Parse(inputDay.Replace("Sunday", "0").Replace("Monday", "1").Replace("Tuesday", "2").Replace("Wednesday", "3").Replace("Thursday", "4").Replace("Friday", "5").Replace("Saturday", "6")));
        }
        int dateDay = (int)date.DayOfWeek;

        int addToBestAnswer = 7;
        foreach (var checkDay in pDays)
        {
            int difference = checkDay - dateDay;
            if (difference<0)
            {
                difference = 7 + difference;
            }
            if (difference<addToBestAnswer&&difference!=0)
            {
                addToBestAnswer = difference;
            }
        }
        DateTime Answer = date.AddDays(addToBestAnswer);
        // Answer.ToShortDateString()+" ("+Answer.DayOfWeek.ToString()+")";
```

Comment: Possible days are listed as string values.

Comment: added solution for that

Answer (score 1):

Like this ?

```
    public DateTime GetNextPossibleDay(DateTime DT, DayOfWeek[] PossibleDays)
    {
        if (PossibleDays.Length == 0)
            throw new Exception("No possible day.");

        do
        {
            DT = DT.AddDays(1);
        }
        while (!PossibleDays.Contains(DT.DayOfWeek));

        return DT;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check every date in the list, unless you get correct one, something like this:

```
   var days = new List<string> {"Tuesday", "Monday"};
   var startDate = new DateTime(2013, 7, 24).AddDays(1);
   while (!days.Contains(startDate.DayOfWeek.ToString("G")))
   {
        startDate = startDate.AddDays(1);
   }
   Console.WriteLine(startDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var date = new DateTime(2013, 07, 24);
var posibleDays = new[]{DayOfWeek.Tuesday,DayOfWeek.Wednesday,DayOfWeek.Friday};

var nearestDay = posibleDays.Select(dow => new { 
    DayOfWeek = dow, 
    Diff = (7 + (dow - date.DayOfWeek)) % 7 
})
.Where(x => x.Diff >= 1)
.OrderBy(x => x.Diff)
.FirstOrDefault();
```

Inspired by a [question of myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219083/get-difference-in-days-between-two-weekdays) some time ago. It assumes a day to be in the next week if the `DayOfWeek` value is earlier than another.

Here a demo with your sample data: http://ideone.com/VzZnzx

Answer (score 1):

Tested. This code works

```
  List<DayOfWeek> days = new List<DayOfWeek>() { DayOfWeek.Tuesday, DayOfWeek.Wednesday };
        DateTime sourceDate = DateTime.Now;
        DayOfWeek currentDay = sourceDate.DayOfWeek;

        int? smallestValue = null;

        foreach (DayOfWeek d in days)
        {
            int currentValue = (int)d - (int)currentDay;
            if (!smallestValue.HasValue)
                smallestValue = currentValue;

            if(smallestValue > currentValue)
                smallestValue = currentValue;

        }

        DateTime nearestDate = sourceDate.AddDays(smallestValue.Value);
```

Comment: Sorry i didn't get your question

Comment: It still suggesting the same day.

Answer (score 1):

Not a fancy Linq, but this works =)

```
    public static DateTime NearestDate(DateTime baseDateTime, List<string> acceptedDays)
    {
        DateTime result = new DateTime(baseDateTime.Year, baseDateTime.Month, baseDateTime.Day);

        List<DayOfWeek> acceptedDoW = new List<DayOfWeek>();
        acceptedDays.ForEach(x => acceptedDoW.Add((DayOfWeek)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), x, true)));

        DayOfWeek currentDay = baseDateTime.DayOfWeek;

        int closestDay = int.MaxValue;

        acceptedDoW.ForEach(x =>
            {
                int currentSpan = (int)x;

                if (x < currentDay)
                    currentSpan += 7;

                currentSpan = currentSpan - (int)currentDay;

                if (currentSpan < closestDay)
                    closestDay = currentSpan;
            });

        return result.AddDays(closestDay);
    }
```